# No rule to make target 'TBB_ENV_LIB_DEBUG-NOTFOUND', needed by 'lib/libopencv_core.so.3.2.0

Tags: c++, opencv, debugging, cmake, tbb

I'm trying to build opencv with the following CMAKE options:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/luca/Dropbox/SURFSPM/opencvInstall -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/opencv_contrib/modules -D WITH_TBB=ON -D WITH_OPENMP=ON -D ENABLE_PROFILING=ON ..
```

Notice that in `RELEASE` mode OpenCV is correctly compiled with all the other options. However, at 43% it returns this error:

```
[ 42%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_perf_optflow
[ 42%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_test_optflow
[ 43%] Generating precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_structured_light_DEBUG.gch
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_core
[ 43%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_test_phase_unwrapping
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'TBB_ENV_LIB_DEBUG-NOTFOUND', needed by 'lib/libopencv_core.so.3.2.0'.  Stop.
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 43%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/system.cpp.o
cc1plus: warning: /home/luca/ParallelOpenCV/opencv/build/modules/core/precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_core_Release.gch: created with -gnone, but used with -gdwarf-2
[ 43%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_test_stitching
[ 43%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_phase_unwrapping
[ 43%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_test_structured_light
[ 43%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_perf_stitching
[ 43%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_stitching
[ 43%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_structured_light
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2161: recipe for target 'modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I think that this is Intel TBB related, but I've installed it (in fact it works with the `RELEASE` version and I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Looks like 'Release' version of TBB library has been found during configuration, but 'Debug' version hasn't. And for unknown reason, that wasn't reported at configuration stage. As fast solution, find variable *TBB_ENV_LIB_DEBUG* in the CMake cache (`CMakeCache.txt` in build tree), and set its value same as for variable *TBB_ENV_LIB_RELEASE*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Tsyvarev's comment hints, indeed the configuration phase fails to pickup a debug library version.

I've gotten success setting the original setting:

```
TBB_ENV_LIB_DEBUG:FILEPATH=TBB_ENV_LIB_DEBUG-NOTFOUND
```

To the same value as `TBB_ENV_LIB:FILEPATH`

```
//Path to a library.
TBB_ENV_LIB:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtbb.so

//Path to a library.
TBB_ENV_LIB_DEBUG:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtbb.so
```